# Why is my DNA band bulging?

Tags: dna, molecular-genetics, lab-techniques, pcr, sds-page

This is the only image my the TA was able to get for us. And, we're using it for our lab report. The image isn't even ours. It's another group's image that we're sharing. But I don't understand why in the first lane there seems to be some bulging/ tapered form of the ladder? Can someone explain why has this happened and how? I am very confused... [image]

Comment: Band distortion can be caused by any number of things. In my experience, everyone has their own their own guesses about the cause and their own little tricks to fix it. Sometimes the gel sets unevenly, or the loading buffer isn't mixed right, or the running buffer isn't at just the right level, or the dye was expired, or the power supply voltage fluctuated. Sometimes an impatient TA changes the settings mid run to speed things along. Whatever the cause, I wouldn't worry about a little distortion as long as you can see your band and it's approximately the right size on the ladder.

Comment: Sometimes molecular techniques can be as much of an art as a science. Just wait until you start doing Western blots.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! It makes much more sense.